# How to Restrict to generate code form my Android .apk?

Tags: android

I want to restrict my Android Application code to regenerate a code using reverse engineering process form my android .apk file. So then my application code will be secure but i don't know how to do this, please help me to restrict reverse engineering process to my android .apk file.

Thanks,
Android Developer.

Comment: use proguard http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do as far as I am aware is to obfuscate your code before deploying it.

Obfuscating, minifying etc will make the original code unreadable even if the code is decompiled.  By unreadable I mean people will not easily be able to tell what variables are used for etc since they will no longer have meaningful names.  The same goes for methods, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"You cannot completely restrict Android apk from decompilation.
 Because it uses dex formats any one can easily convert these dex files into jar file using publicly available tools like dex2jar.
 But you can Obfuscate code to reduce code readability, you can also use native codes to prevent easy decompilation of code.
You can store some part your code in server and download them at runtime call function in library using Reflection concept,
which will help you to prevent your code from decompilation."